# Naming conventions for intercepting input property changes

Tags: angular, angular6

In the style guides it is [advised](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#properties-and-methods) to not prefix variables with underscored

But in this particular [example](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#intercept-input-property-changes-with-a-setter) I've seen it was used like this:

```
@Input() set testVariable(value) {
    this._testVariable= value;
}
```

When intercepting an Input, is there a naming convention for the class variable?

Answer (score 0):

Using underscore as prefix it's OK for **private** variable if You have setter/getter. If You don't like it maybe better create method `setTestVariable(value)` instead of setter.